# Convert Wav to Ogg

Tags: macos, wav, ogg

I have a folder with a large number of Wav files which I wish to convert to Ogg. How do I do this for the latest release of Mac Os X. I have tried to run Drop Ogg X but it does not work, complaining instead that it does not support PowerPC. The fact is my machine is a 2013 Macbook.

I also dowloaded libogg-1.1 and ran:

```
.configure
make 
sudo make install
```

Not sure though what I have installed and where to find it.

I wish to add the ogg files to my html5 webpage in order to support firefox.

Comment: A library (lib) doesn’t do anything by itself. I suggest you use [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/) and install ffmpeg.

Answer (score 7):

Simply download a static build of ffmpeg from [ffmpeg.org](http://ffmpeg.org/download.html), extract it, and use that:

```
ffmpeg -i input.wav -c:a libvorbis -qscale:a 3 output.ogg
```

This will convert the audio to Vorbis, using the default quality of 3. The quality range is 0–10 where 10 is the highest.